# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "From": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
String CREATE_TABLE_MSG="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_MSG+"("+FROM+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"+STATUS+" TEXT,"+MESSAGE+" TEXT,"+PIC+" TEXT,"+TYPE+" TEXT,"+TIME+" TEXT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+SENDID+" TEXT AUTOINCREMENT"+")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MSG);
```

Comment: **Wild guess**: You named a coulumn in your table `From`. This is **not allowed**.

Comment: `From` is a reserved word. As in `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: @cricket_007 Right. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [SQLite keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

`FROM` is one of them. Case insensitive.

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it

So, you need to quote the from column

```
CREATE TABLE messages (`FROM` TEXT PRIMARY KEY
```

Or, just rename the column so it isn't a keyword like `_from`

Comment: Though standard SQL should be used preferably. So `"` instead of `\``.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to use it, though. Plus it's easier on the eyes with concatenation in Java strings

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `From` is a [keyword in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). If you really need to use it as a column name, you have to quote it.

> ```
> 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> ```